# Do native English speakers use the word 'notif' to mean ‘notification’ or ‘alert’?

Tags: slang, clipping

This question is quite subjective as it probably depends on where you live. I was wondering whether the shortened version of *notification* — [“notif.”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/notif) — was used in spoken language. In French we tend to use this exact same shortening when we talk about social media “alerts”.

If you do use “notif.”, how familiar do you consider it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73190/discussion-on-question-by-christian-g-do-native-english-speakers-use-the-word).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To answer your direct question, no, **'notif' is not used at all** in American English (I can't speak to other varieties), **in speech**.

There's a general question here though and that is how, in general, English abbreviations are made.

The [bulk of abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_abbreviations) in English **tend to be acronyms**, the initials of the words making up the phrase ('USA' for United States of America), or removing vowels and inferable consonants, only for writing ('abbrv' pronounced 'abbreviation').

Of those that are not initialisms, **the most common method is to use the first syllable**, ('lab' for 'laboratory', 'teen' for 'teenager'). For a counter example, 'computer' doesn't have a good abbreviation; the first syllable is unstressed and I don't know why but 'puter' just sounds awful and anyway no one says that out loud.

There are some very rare instances where an unstressed final syllable is done ('za' for pizza).

But on the whole, *if* there is a word shortening, it is the first syllable and it is usually closed and accented.

The general rule, if you can call it a rule, [when abbreviating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(morphology)) is that **the result should sound natural according to a languages phonology**. Short words in English tend to be CVC (ConsonantVowelConsonant). French syllables try to avoid closing, so tend to be CV (ConsonantVowel).

You may wonder then what *is* the abbreviation for 'notification' in English speech (because certainly that word is uncomfortably long in any language). And the answer is probably ... 'alert'. Yes, I realize that is a different word, so not really a shortening. But there is no shortening of 'notification' that people use in English speech.

Of course, in writing and especially in texting, all sorts of ways to shorten typing are used: 2 for to, r for are, etc. There is enough evidence of 'notif' in texting, whether by logical reinvention every time or by culture, that it should be recognized as a repeatable pattern. But in speech, 'notif' just hasn't caught on at all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73192/discussion-on-answer-by-mitch-do-native-english-speakers-use-the-word-notif-to).

Comment: Interesting (and tangentially relevant to this question) is that, as you say, there is no good abbreviation for computer, while in Russian, there is,—"comp".

Answer (score 87):

I've never heard it, in fact I wouldn't even vocalise it to myself as "notif" if I saw it on a device. I'd just think "I've got a notification" or "which programming language is that, does it mean 'elseif'?".

Having said that it could well be current with the hipster/pseudo-cool/trendy crowd who use phrases like "totes amazeballs"; I wouldn't know.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73191/discussion-on-answer-by-boldben-do-native-english-speakers-use-the-word-notif).

Answer (score 19):

According to my chat histories I've used the word "notif" at least 3 times in the last month, and I've definitely used it in real life. I'm also an Aussie, and we [like to shorten our words](http://www.australiangeographic.com.au/topics/history-culture/2012/09/aussie-slang-why-we-shorten-words/), which I think is totes amazeballs.

Comment: The question specifically asks about spoken language.  I'd think it would be much more rare in spoken that written (or typed) language.

Comment: Shouldn't it be noto(s) on your mobes?

Comment: @NickT I think an Aussie would be more likely to come up with "notie" than "noto"  :-)

Answer (score 14):

Native speaker of American English here.  "Notif" makes sense as an abbreviation in *text*, and I've probably seen it in software source code, but I'm also quite sure I have never heard it spoken *verbally*, even by the various totes amazeballs hipsters I know (granting that I don't know *all* of the totes amazeballs hipsters).

It's an awkward abbreviation in spoken English because of the stress pattern of "notification".  It can't be pronounced as /noʊˈtɪf/, which would be read as 〈no tiff〉 as in the absence of quarrel.  So it must be either /ˈnoʊtɪf/, like 〈notice〉 /ˈnoʊtɪs/, or /noʊˈtiːf/, like 〈motif〉 /moʊˈtiːf/—but for both of those the only sound distinguishing it from its cousin is a consonant of the same manner of articulation (nasal, fricative) in an unstressed syllable.

As others have noted, the word is so awkward to abbreviate that English speakers will tend to choose a different synonym altogether, like "alert" or "notice" or "ping", rather than even try to abbreviate it.

Comment: +1 - whether it's ever used or not, the fact its pronunciation is so close to a lot of much more common words (and isn't exactly "standard" due to how uncommonly it's spoken) is definitely potential for confusion and worth noting by any English learner.

Comment: I pronounce it /noʊˈtɪf/-- I don't see why you say you can't pronounce it in such a way. Admittedly I don't think I've ever said "tiff" in my life either...

Answer (score 6):

Ultimately, whatever the opinion or experiences of people on this thread, "notif" will be understood by some people and not understood by others.

Abbreviations are much more common in written language, and in social media in particular, where there is often a need (or desire) to be terse, due to limited space, character limits, a dislike of typing (or entering text with one's fingers), or simply being in a hurry.

Thus, one could probably find many examples of "notif" in online communications, regardless of whether it's made the dictionary as a "common" abbreviation.

You ask about spoken language in particular.  It's much harder to provide concrete evidence about spoken language, as it is generally not recorded in digital form and search-indexed.  But, abbreviations such as this are much less common in spoken language, partly because they might not really save any time, but mainly because they're just **confusing**: the "covenant" between speaker and listener requires the speaker to try avoid confusion.  So, if we're focused on spoken language (which you asked about), then I can confidently say that **most people would not use 'notif' to mean 'notification' in spoken language.**

Comment: Yes ... understood by some people, and not by others.  Seeing "notif", I though it meant "not if".

Comment: there’s a lot of variance among the common “abbreviations” but today they are generally *not* used for the reasons you describe. While they may have started out that way, words like *lmao* are not interchangeable with *laugh my ass off*.

Answer (score 5):

This may be generational, but **yes**, *notif* is used commonly as a stand-in for *notification*. I would go so far as to say that *notif* is the one that most people I interact with use primarily, and *notification* is the pedantic form, like *TV* vs *television*.

Note that while *notif* is a bit more common on social media than it is in spoken language (though I’ve heard it in both), I would call it more slang than abbreviation. Social media and texting has long moved past the point where words were abbreviated just to save typing; *notification* is no exception. Note that almost all of the extant “[texting abbreviations](https://twitter.com/jennmcallister/status/958239788884115456)”, e.g. *oomf*, or *lol* have specific semantics that long since diverged from those of their long forms.

Also, in response to Mitch’s answer, the short form of *notification* is most certainly not *alert* which I have never heard in any context outside of missiles. This is probably for no reason other than Apple deciding to use the word *notifications* to refer to its lockscreen messages, and the fact that iPhones have the predominant market share among the younger generation.

---

Note to downvoters: it is difficult to find meaningful evidence regarding the usage of *notif* and similar slang, especially if you want data on *spoken* frequency. Standard methods like counting occurrences and frequency of use on Google’s index will be affected by the choice of sample pool more than anything else. *notif* will naturally be hard to find in say, a search of Google Books, while I would expect it to be predominant on Twitter or iMessage. The former isn’t exactly known for providing credible statistics, the latter is impossible. As with anything regarding slang terms, “personal experience” is the only reliable source.

---

Although a handful of examples does not prove a trend, here are some public, recent (~1–2 months old) tweets from *people that I follow* that use *notif*.

https://twitter.com/thisdressx/status/960636808462729216

> I JUMPED RIGHT OUT OF MY SEAT WHEN I SAW THE NOTIF

https://twitter.com/breadstickerin/status/949215772982824960

> WAIT DO YOU GET A NOTIF WHEN PEOPLE DO THAT

https://twitter.com/lovedswifts/status/954413958533873664

> idk why but your notif didn’t pop up ???

The important takeaway here is that *notification* is the only word that’s been “shortened” here†, even though there are a number of typing-saving reductions that could have been used, e.g. *people* → *ppl*, *you* → *u*, *your* → *ur*. The last person has even elected to include a (curly) apostrophe in the word *didn’t*, a relatively unwieldy character to type on an iPhone keyboard. This indicates that *notif* was used for reasons other than reducing typing.

† You might have noticed the usage of *idk*. Without getting too much into the nitty gritty of twitter slang, *idk* is indeed used as a true abbreviation, but it’s so ubiquitous that it’s essentially the canonical form of *I don’t know* now which makes it a somewhat special case. *idk* is also atomic; no one writes *dk* for *don’t know*.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or something of a native English speaker using "notif"? I'm curious who you interact with that uses it frequently, because i've never heard it. Maybe bilingual Canada?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai iOS’s search is a little weird but a search for *notif* in Messages gives 3 results (3 is the maximum the UI displays), the first 2 are messages I received, the 3rd is one I sent. I’m not attaching the screenshot partly for privacy reasons and partly because you can’t upload images to comments.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai more investigation on twitter shows it seems to be determined on an individual level. Some people prefer to use *notif* while others only use *notification*. I doubt many people are even conscious of this (I wasn’t until I read this question).

Comment: Well, you can always add images to your post. Maybe a tweet, then?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai here’s a (recentish) tweet from someone I follow (you can find anything in a global Twitter search which makes such a search meaningless): https://twitter.com/breadstickerin/status/949215772982824960 . Note she doesn’t reduce the words *you* or *people* so clearly, typing/character space pressure/laziness is not a relevant factor here.

Comment: Cool. Add it to your post and I'll upvote it

Comment: @Azor-Ahai done

Comment: I can't agree that this term is commonly used. Twitter has an arbitrary character limit that encourages people to abbreviate, but that doesn't make it English usage. .

Comment: @barbecue not likely. those tweets don’t come anywhere near the 280 limit and at any rate there are other words that could be abbreviated but aren’t. Therefore character limit pressure cannot be a factor here.

Comment: @taylorswift What country are you hearing or seeing this in? I have never heard or seen the abbreviation notif here in the US.

Comment: The apostrophes in my iPhone texts are mostly generated by autocorrect/predictive typing. I don't know how you get the algorithm to insert curved apostrophes rather than straight ones, but I wouldn't be surprised to find out there's a way to do it. I would not assume that the existence of such an apostrophe where an apostrophe is obviously expected is a sign of extra effort in typing.

Comment: @taylorswift Tweets are not standard English usage, they rely heavily on abbreviations and hashtags. And the 280 limit is also very new. 140 was the limit for many years. You know all this already, though.

Comment: @barbecue i’m sorry but this is not an accurate description of how (the younger generation) talks on twitter. unironic usage of hashtags is almost unheard of. abbreviations are less common than the stereotype assumes (no one says actually says gr8!) and a lot of them have subtle meanings. And by the way, all the tweets I gave as examples are after the 280 was introduced.

Comment: I appreciate your examples, but I would disagree on "DK." I've seen it used plenty.

Comment: @Taylorswift I never said anything about how the younger generation talks on Twitter. I really don't understand why you're insisting that Twitter defines standard English usage. It does not.

Answer (score 5):

I am Australian. Until I read this question I had never heard of "notif" as a word at all, let alone one used in spoken English. If I heard it spoken I would probably assume someone had said "motive".

If you want to be generally understood, I suggest you not use "notif" in speech.

---

Having said that, I am a programmer, and might possibly interpret "notif" as "not if", that is some sort of negative conditional. However if it was pronounced to rhyme with "motive" (like "mote ... if") then I would think you were saying "motive".

Comment: I agree.  I'm also a developer.  I never shorten 'notification' in speech, but in the right context I would use ntf / NTF in messages

Answer (score 3):

I live in the Silicon Valley (Bay Area, California), a giant center of software tech businesses. We use "notif" in spoken language here (pronounced "NOtiff", softening the "t" almost like "NOdiff").

(Also, I was born here and grew up here, and would be considered by most to be "native".)

Comment: I never once heard "notif" in spoken English in over 6 years in living in the Bay Area. Maybe it's a common argot at your company; I would hesitate to extrapolate from there.

Comment: I also live in Silicon Valley; I asked a few people (including natives) about this and none of them had ever heard of this usage. Actually they all looked at me like I was crazy for bringing it up. So all we know is that _some_ people in the area use it, but I agree that it's unjustified to extrapolate that it's more common here than elsewhere, at least not without a lot more data.

Answer (score 1):

I speak 3 varieties of English (southeastern British, Irish, South African) well enough to be taken for a native speaker, and it's unfamiliar to me as a spoken word. If I heard it spoken I might mistake it for *motive*. In an online posting it is perfectly obvious what it means. I would still hesitate to use it myself. It never does to adopt slang one doesn't really know how to use appropriately.

Comment: SE British isn't, as far as I'm concerned, a 'variety of English'.

Comment: @ Lordology But I take it that in your view the other two are?

Comment: Well, as they're separate countries. yes.

Comment: I suggest you write to the OED edtors making your point that their regional label South-East England is unnecessary and redundant.

Comment: I never stated it wasn't a region.  It is.  You say 'I speak'.  I am saying, there is no specific 'variety' of the Spoken English language called 'South East English'.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard 'notif' used in spoken English in the United States. In context of your example, I would say "social media post" (where post would be short for posting as in posting a message). Do a Google search for "social media post" for many examples.